# Preventing floods while saving logs

Tags: python, comparative-review, logging, redis

I had a logging function…

```
@task
def log_request(label, target, request_as_dict):
    # Detect flood

    # In general this task do not process misuse. But it can send
    # an alarm to another celery task if something strange happened.
    if incr_with_ttl(INDICATOR_KEY, INDICATOR_TTL) >= INDICATOR_THRESHOLD:
        process_misuse.apply_async()
        redis.delete(INDICATOR_KEY)

    # Save entry
    fields = request_as_dict['fields']
    fields.update({
        "label": label,
        "type": 1 if target else 2, # 1: target, 2: extra

        "suspicion": suspicion_rating(request_as_dict),
        "raw_request": request_as_dict
    })
    RequestEntry.objects.create(**fields)
```

… that I rewrote using two inner functions for readability.

```
@task
def log_request(label, target, request_as_dict):

    def detect_flood():
        '''
        In general this task do not process misuse. But it can send
        an alarm to another celery task if something strange happened.
        '''
        if incr_with_ttl(INDICATOR_KEY, INDICATOR_TTL) >= INDICATOR_THRESHOLD:
            process_misuse.apply_async()
            redis.delete(INDICATOR_KEY)

    def save_entry():
        fields = request_as_dict['fields']
        fields.update({
            "label": label,
            "type": 1 if target else 2, # 1: target, 2: extra

            "suspicion": suspicion_rating(request_as_dict),
            "raw_request": request_as_dict
        })
        RequestEntry.objects.create(**fields)

    save_entry()
    detect_flood()
```

Is the rewrite an improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have recognized that this function is actually doing two things.  Compartmentalizing the functionality, therefore, is a good idea.  However, that's not the best way to go about it.

My first observation is that you call `save_entry()` before `detect_flood()`, whereas the inner functions are defined in the other order.  That's misleading.

My second minor observation is that the docstring doesn't really describe what `detect_flood()` does.  It seems like it should be more of a comment.

I would consider `save_entry()` to be the real work for `log_request()`.  The flood detection code has very little to do with it.  In fact, `detect_flood()` doesn't even use any of the parameters `label`, `target`, and `request_as_dict`.  Therefore, the flood detection functionality would be better written as a `@rate_limited` **decorator** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is fine.

By the *single responsibility principle*, and to achieve *functional cohesion*, a function should do one thing. As the responsibility of this function takes two logical steps, it makes sense to move those steps to their own functions. And since these functions are only used once, and so they would not be useful not desirable in the global namespace, it makes sense to hide them as inner functions.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `fields.update()`, you're actually modifying `request_as_dict`.  That is unexpected behaviour from the caller's point of view, especially since you didn't warn about it in a docstring.

A more appropriate implementation would be

```
@task
def log_request(label, target, request_as_dict):
    # Detect flood
    # …

    # Save entry
    RequestEntry.objects.create(**dict(
        request_as_dict['fields'],
        "label": label,
        "type": 1 if target else 2, # 1: target, 2: extra
        "suspicion": suspicion_rating(request_as_dict),
        "raw_request": request_as_dict
    ))
```